# Print lines read from file on same line

Tags: python

I've tried many different things to achieve this, simply I want this:

```
import requests
path1 = 'D:\test\Files\/results.txt'
lines1 = open(path1).readlines()
ctr = 0
for i in lines1:
    try:
        r = requests.get(i)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            ctr += 1
            print(i, " Status Code: ", r.status_code)
except requests.ConnectionError:
    ctr += 1
    print(i, " Failed to connect")
print("Counter", ctr)
```

to output like this:

```
URL Status Code: xyz
```

But instead I'm getting:

```
URL
Status Code: xyz
```

So, what's the best way to print out something in the same line with Python?

Comment: Believe me, I've tried. Isn't working

Comment: Python 3.x or Python 2.7.X?

Comment: 'This is Python version 3.4.3'

Comment: Where is it that you are print URL? Is it already in the file?

Comment: i = URLs from the file.

Comment: merely looking at the contents of `i` would have shown you what was causing the problem . . .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is a line. Just strip it to remove any possible newline at the end, before printing it:

```
 print(i.rstrip(), " Status Code: ", r.status_code)
```

Comment: @Leustad You can thank JuniorCompressor and let others with this problem know that this solved it for you by clicking the green tick to accept the answer.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor Sorry, I got caught up with something else while waiting for the countdown(10mins?) There you go.

Comment: Don't apologize. Everything is ok